# Angular 1 - Improve angular.element/multiple parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, jqlite

```
const page = angular.element('#contact-history')
this.scrollContainer = page ? page.parent().parent().parent() : null
```

How can you improve the code and avoid multiple `parent()` using Angular 1

The DOM, I want selected `overlay-content` id :

```
<div id="overlay-content" class="overlay-content container-fluid ng-scope">
    <h1><span translate="" translate-values="{ section: $ctrl.overlayTitle }" class="ng-scope">My Historie</span>
    <ui-view class="ng-scope">
       <contact-history contact="::$resolve.contact" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
          <div class="row contact-history" id="contact-history">
          </div>
       </my-iad-contact-history>
    </ui-view>
    <div ui-view="overlay" class="overlay ng-scope"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What element are you trying to get to?

Comment: @Jerinaw this is added

Comment: `this.scrollContainer = page ? page.parents('div#overlay-content'): null` ? try this ? hope u have jquery included

Comment: @Rahul no, jquery is not included

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri you may need to include jquery to work this out..

Comment: You're saying the element has an Id, IDs should be unique. $document.getElementById('overlay-content'). Or angular.element('#overlay-content')

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
this.scrollContainer = page ? angular.element(document).find('#overlay-content') : null
```